# Need to reduce runtime to delete strikethrough characters

Tags: excel, vba

Excel workbook consist of 10,000 rows and 25 columns and take 15 mins to complete this process. i need to reduce the runtime to complete this process into less than 1 min. kindly help me out from this situtaion.

```
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(2)
        For i = Len(cl.Value) To 1 Step -1
            If cl.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                cl.Characters(i, 1).Delete
            End If
     Next i
   Next cl
```

Comment: Have you turned off screen updating? That will make a big difference. Would be helpful to tell us what you already tried if anything.

Comment: How many total cells are you processing?  What percentage of them have strikethrough text?  Is the struck-through text whole word/phrases, or single letters only?

Comment: @TimWilliams. i have used this concept also at starting "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" and completed with "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" at the ending

Comment: What about my other questions?

Comment: strike through may be single letter to multiple lines. this may occur in 6000 to 8000 cells. and close to 40% of information will be in strike through

Comment: Posted a very fast solution analyzing the **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value** where I tested 10,000 rows/ 26 columns within only **8.94 secs** (vs. Tim's valid & refined `.Characters` approach in 846,38 secs :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Very fast approach via xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value**

Using the relatively unknown **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value**, also referred to as ►.Value(11) solves the question by a very simple string replacement (though the xml string handling can reveal to be very complicated under special conditions).

This approach (quickly tested for 10000 rows) seems to be up to *90 times faster* as Tim's valid solution refining the original code, but lasting 14 minutes :-)

```
Sub RemoveStrThr(rng As Range, Optional colOffset As Long = 1)
'a) Get range data as xml spreadsheet value
    Dim xmls As String: xmls = rng.Value(xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet) ' //alternatively: xmls = rng.Value(11)
'b) find start position of body
    Dim pos As Long: pos = InStr(xmls, "<Worksheet ")
'c) define xml spreadsheet parts and remove <S>-node sections in body
    Dim head As String: head = Left(xmls, pos - 1)
    Dim body As String: body = Mid(xmls, pos)
    'remove strike throughs
    Dim results: results = Split(Replace(body, "</S>", "^<S>"), "<S>")
    results = Filter(results, "^", False)       ' negative filtering of special char "^"         
    body = Join(results, "")
'd) write cleaned range back
    rng.Offset(0, colOffset).Value(11) = head & body
End Sub
```

**Example call**

```
Sub TestRemove()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim t As Double
    t = Timer
    
    RemoveStrThr Sheet1.Range("A2:Z10000"), 27              ' << change to your needs
    
    Debug.Print "done", Format(Timer - t, "0.00 secs")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Help reference links**

- [Excel XlRangeValueDataType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.xlrangevaluedatatype)
- [Excel Range Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)

**Addendum** *(due to @Tim' valuable comment)*

Note that *if the whole cell content should be struck out then this will not remove the struck-out content: there are no `<S>` or `</S>` tags in the  element, since the strikethrough is applied via a Style rule* (via the xml spreadsheet value head).

To meet this eventuality

> *"...you could add a second step using something like `Application.FindFormat.Font.Strikethrough = True: rng.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchFormat:=True: Application.FindFormat.Clear` to take care of those cells."*

Comment: Nice solution !

Comment: FYI if the whole cell content is struck out then this will not remove the struck-out content: there are no <S> or </S> tags in the <Cell> element, since the strikethrough is applied via a Style rule.

Comment: ...you could add a second step using something like `Application.FindFormat.Font.Strikethrough = True: rng.Replace What:="*", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchFormat:=True: Application.FindFormat.Clear` to take care of those cells

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input, appreciate it! Treating all aspects of `.Value(11)` would be worth other questions :-) @TimWilliams

Comment: Nice! Voted it up. As Tim Williams mentioned, it will skip the cells where all text is struck out. It looks that Excel creates styles (using random numbers, unfortunately) for such cases. Not only one style... All created styles ends in `ss:StrikeThrough="1"` (at least contains this string, in the Font tag). They can be identified searching for it and I tried splitting the body by `vbCrLf` and replacing the rows/elements containing `StyleID="s380"` (380 was one of the created styles). It worked in terms of making the string disappearing, but all the row cells are skipped back...

Comment: The row Tag needs cells in the order they appear, a empty one without `<Data> tag` (<Cell ss:StyleID="s216"/>, for instance) or the first one to have `ss:Index="2"` if first cell should be skipped...

Answer (score 2):

Any use of the Characters collection tends to be kind of slow, so the best you can do (beyond turning off screenupdating) is get some minor improvements by (eg) ignoring cells with no strikethrough, checking for cases where all content is struck through, and batching your calls to `Delete`.

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim t
    
    Range("C1:C3").Copy Range("A1:A999") 'creating some dummy cell values (no/mixed/all ST)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    t = Timer
    
    RemoveStrikeThrough Range("A1:A999")
    
    Debug.Print "done", Timer - t

End Sub

Sub RemoveStrikeThrough(rng As Range)
    Dim cl As Range, hasST, i As Long, pos As Long, st As Boolean
    For Each cl In rng.Cells
        'only process cells which have any strikethrough style applied
        '  hasST will be False (no ST), True (all ST) or Null (mixed ST)
        hasST = cl.Font.Strikethrough
        
        If TypeName(hasST) = "Boolean" Then
            If hasST Then
                cl.ClearContents 'all text is struck out, so clear the cell
            Else
                'Debug.Print "No strikethrough", cl.Address
            End If
        Else
            'mixed - do char by char
            For i = Len(cl.Value) To 1 Step -1
                If cl.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
                    If Not st Then 'new run?
                        st = True
                        pos = i
                    End If
                Else
                    If st Then 'previous run?
                        cl.Characters(i + 1, pos - i).Delete
                        st = False
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            'remove last strikethough if any
            If st Then cl.Characters(1, pos).Delete
            st = False 'reset this
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: Fine & valid solution +:) - As this seems to be a speed issue, I posted a very fast alternative via the relatively unknown **xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value** plus a very basic string replacement (doing without XML namespace declarations and replacements). @TimWilliams

Comment: @TimWilliams. Thanks for your support. With your help i have successfully completed the program and runtime of the program is 2 mins, but the goal of the program runtime should be less than a minute. Unable to use "xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet Value" due to spreadsheet having formuals and formats. Could you please help me to reduce leadtime for this program below a minute.

Comment: If you can share an example workbook with representative content and your current code I could take a look.

Comment: @TimWilliams i have tried xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet value also but it not suitable for our file.  i have shared my Automation tool and Sample workbook. Please let me if you need any details. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MaCB7L1zwO6uEZl9b87A59xPJ3ptoapv?usp=sharing

Comment: @TimWilliams i gave the folder access. Thank you for your support

Comment: OK I will take a look later today.

Comment: See - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ofI6SeyMeUN8ieigHUK68GAyVBJIWcES/view?usp=sharing   Did about 5k rows in ~40secs.  Not super-fast but possibly the best you can do given any constraints.